# require() an html file in browserify npm build

Tags: angularjs, browserify, require

I see some issues when I'm using require() to include contents of an html file in my angular component. I'll copy paste only those sections that are relevant to the issue i am facing.

Here is what my top-nav component looks like.

```
angular.module('topNavModule', [])
.component('topNav', {
    //bindings: { 
    //},
    template: require('./topNav.html')
});
```

When i add the top-nav component in my main index.html file i see [object Object]. Please note when i add the html inline (instead of require()) i see the HTML correctly.

My topNav.html is just some simple html code enclosed in `. Is there anything else i need to do to make require() html work correctly?

Comment: You're module needs to export your string...

Comment: Can you include your Browserify configuration in your question? Are you using [`stringify`](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify)?

Comment: @cartant I simply installed and am using Browserify. So maybe using the default configuration! Do we need some additional node modules to make this work?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Is there anyway we can do this without doing the module.exports thing?

Comment: Yep, have a look at [`stringify`](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify).

Comment: Browserify is just a CommonJS system. Perhaps you want something like Webpack instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i was actually looking for [partialify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/partialify) node module.

require()-able HTML, CSS, and (potentially) more
require() file contents of HTML, CSS and (potentially) more into a variable as a string.

Comment: the second paragraph is pretty unintelligible, but the partialify module is indeed what I needed